# How to label items

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate, theorems

Is it possible to label items in latex in the following manner:

> We have the following theorem:
>
> Theorem 3.2
>
> (I) bla bla bla
>
> (II) ble ble ble
>
> (III) bli bli bli

So I would like to call the item (II):

> We see easily by the theorem 3.2 (II) that...

Is there any command I can write in the latex file to have "3.2 (II)" displayed automatically in the PDF? the standard commands "\label, \ref" don't give me what I want.

Thanks

Comment: Which package(s) do you use at present to format and number theorems and, possibly, enumerated items?

Answer (score 17):

Hope this is what you're looking for. With the help of `enumitem` package, we can define the reference to an item to be `\thethm (\Roman*)` so to incorporate the theorem number.

Note that you have to change `\thethm` to the counter you're using for your theorems.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}
\section{Theorems}

\begin{thm}
  We have the following theorem:
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\upshape(\Roman*),ref=\thethm (\Roman*)]
    \item\label{th:first} bla bla bla
    \item\label{th:second} ble ble ble
    \item\label{th:third} bli bli bli
  \end{enumerate}
\end{thm}

We see easily by the theorem \ref{th:second} that...

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

If you need to have the theorem header immediately followed by the list, you can add `before=\leavevmode` to the options of the `enumerate` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}
\section{Theorems}
We have the following theorem:

\begin{thm}
  \begin{enumerate}[before=\leavevmode,label=\upshape(\Roman*),ref=\thethm (\Roman*)]
    \item\label{th:first} bla bla bla
    \item\label{th:second} ble ble ble
    \item\label{th:third} bli bli bli
  \end{enumerate}
\end{thm}

We see easily by the theorem \ref{th:second} that...

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using a "basic" document class (such as `article`), you could proceed as follows:

- Load the `ntheorem` package and select a theorem style that inserts a line break after the header,
- use the `chngcntr` package to assure that the numbering of theorems starts afresh at each new section, and
- reset the low-level LaTeX paramaters `\theenumi`, `\labelenumi`, and `\p@enumi` suitably to get upright-shape uppercase-Roman numerals, with the theorem number pre-fixed when used in cross-references.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

%% A. Theorem style with line break after header
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
%% B. Number theorems by section 
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{theorem}{section}
%% C. Labelling of level-1 enumerated items
\renewcommand\theenumi{\textup{(\Roman{enumi})}}
\renewcommand\labelenumi{\theenumi}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@enumi{\thetheorem\,}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{3} % just for this example
\setcounter{theorem}{1}

\begin{theorem}
\begin{enumerate}
   \item bla bla bla
   \item \label{item:2} ble ble ble
   \item bli bli bli
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

As we can easily see by Theorem \ref{item:2}, \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I label items if I use them as follows: `\item[(4.1)]`